# How do I make Fancy Food?

Tags: epic-astro-story

I researched a Processing Plant to make Fancy Food, and a type of Processed Item that uses Fancy Food (Chocolate Cakes) but I can't set the Processing Plant to actually make the Chocolate Cakes.

What am I missing? How do I make Fancy Food?

Comment: Processing Plants only improve the rank of your raw materials - you'll still need to take the fancy food from the processing plant to a factory in order to produce your Chocolate Cakes.  I don't know if this is enough to point you in the right direction or not, so this is a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: Also it should be noted that Chocolate Cakes require Food Level 3, whereas making the Fancy Food requires Processing Level 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments and the production chain as laid out in [this french wiki post](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwikikairofrance.free.fr%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DChaines_de_production_Epic_Astro), you're on the right track.

You need 3 different things to produce something in this game:

1. Materials
2. Something able to produce something with those materials
3. Somewhere to use/sell what you produce

In your case, you've probably got 1. Food which is the material that the processing plant needs to make the fancy food. and 2. A processing plant requiring processing level 1 or above to make fancy food. **What you're missing is something to do with the fancy food as fancy food is yet another material and not a finished product.**

So you want to have chocolate cake be the thing to use your fancy food, then **you need something to produce chocolate cake, which as per the comments/french wiki page is a factory and Food Level 3.** Chocolate cake is a finished product and will go to your exporter for sale.